# Handling integer times in R

Tags: r, dataframe, strptime

Times in my data frame are recorded as integers as in: 1005,1405,745,1130,2030 etc. How do I convert these integers so R will understand and use it in functions such as strptime. Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: try  lubridate::hm(1005)

Comment: `strptime("1005", format = "%H%M")` gives `"2016-04-21 10:05:00 EDT"`, so I guess you can do `strptime(as.character(1005), format="%H%M")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution using strptime()

As was pointed out by [Psidom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4983450/psidom) in his comment, you can convert the integers to character and use `strptime()`:

```
int_times <- c(1005,1405,745,1130,2030)
strptime(as.character(int_times), format="%H%M")
## [1] "2016-04-21 10:05:00 CEST" "2016-04-21 14:05:00 CEST" NA                        
## [4] "2016-04-21 11:30:00 CEST" "2016-04-21 20:30:00 CEST"
```

However, as you can see, you run into trouble as soon as the number has only three digits. You can get around this by using `formatC()` to format the integers to character with four digits and a leading zero (if needed):

```
char_times <- formatC(int_times, flag = 0, width = 4)
char_times
[1] "1005" "1405" "0745" "1130" "2030"
```

Now, conversion works:

```
strptime(char_times, format="%H%M")
## [1] "2016-04-21 10:05:00 CEST" "2016-04-21 14:05:00 CEST" "2016-04-21 07:45:00 CEST"
## [4] "2016-04-21 11:30:00 CEST" "2016-04-21 20:30:00 CEST"
```

Note that `strptime()` always returns a POSIXct object that involves time *and* date. Since no data was given, the current day was used. But you could also use `paste()` to combine the times with any date:

```
strptime(paste("2010-03-21", char_times), format="%Y-%m-%d %H%M")
## [1] "2010-03-21 10:05:00 CET" "2010-03-21 14:05:00 CET" "2010-03-21 07:45:00 CET"
## [4] "2010-03-21 11:30:00 CET" "2010-03-21 20:30:00 CET"
```

### Solution using lubridate::hm()

As was suggested by [Richard Telford](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2055765/richard-telford) in his comment, you could also make use of lubridate's `period` class, if you prefer not to have any date involved. This class is for periods of times and thus you could represent a clock time, say 10:23, as the period 10 hours, 23 minutes. However, simply using `hm()` from lubridate does not work:

```
library(lubridate)
hm(char_times)
## [1] NA NA NA NA NA
## Warning message:
## In .parse_hms(..., order = "HM", quiet = quiet) :
##   Some strings failed to parse
```

The reason is that without a separator, it is not clear how these times should be converted. `hm()` just expects a representation that has hours before minutes. But `"1005"` could be 100 hours and 5 minutes just as well as 1 hour and 5 minutes. So you need to introduce a separation between hours and minutes, which you could do for instance as follows:

```
char_times2 <- paste(substr(char_times, 1, 2), substr(char_times, 3, 4))
hm(char_times2)
## [1] "10H 5M 0S"  "14H 5M 0S"  "7H 45M 0S"  "11H 30M 0S" "20H 30M 0S"
```

Note that I have again used the fixed width string represantation `char_times`, because then the hours are always given by the first two characters. This makes it easy to use `substr()`.